# Guardar un registro que se va a borrar en una tabla

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, crud

Buenas noches tengo un crud en spring boot y mysql, y necesito borrar un registro, pero este dato lo debo de almacenar en una tabla, como lo puedo hacer sin usar trigger?

Comment: ¿Insertarlo antes de hacer la eliminación no es una opción?

Comment: ya el registro esta en la base de datos solo tengo que eliminarlo pero pasarlo a una tabla